# Electron-compile not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm bit hesitant to make this post, because I feel like I'm being very stupid, but I would like to know what I'm doing wrong.

I have attempted to create an [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/) app with [electron-compile](https://github.com/electron/electron-compile). However, it behaves exactly like a regular electron app, it doesn't compile anything, and it gives no errors in the terminal(it of course gives all kinds of errors in the dev tools), I have no clue what the problem is, and it's really quite aggravating since this is supposed to be a very easy thing to use.

Comment: electron-compile is relatively a new compiler for electron , so you will certainly experience some edge cases (config from scratch) where you will have to dig deep and debug ,my advice is to use a boilerplate.less pain and more fun.

Comment: @Sam, the interesting thing is, I have tried using a boilerplate, still no success. I've also tried upgrade my Node/NPM versions to latest version and latest LTS version. It just seem to work at all on my computer.

Comment: I purged my system of all things Node and NPM, then reinstalled, now everything is working normally.